# clipboard operation between LibreOffice and other application

Tags: google-chrome, libreoffice, clipboard

When I want to copy text from LibreOffice to an gmail in the Chrome browser, the clipboard does not work unless I keep the text document of LibreOffice open.

How can I fix this limitation or is it just a matter of waiting for improvements?

Comment: See this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/983449 Although my version of LibreOffice is direct and not from the Ubuntu repo. This should be an upstream issue: https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48783

Comment: At the bottom of the second bug there's a link to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence and that has "Clipboard persistence is a bug that affects many programs under Ubuntu and other X11-based operating systems. " Worth a look.

Comment: With the use of KDE which by default includes Klipper clipboard manager, I'm not seeing this "bug".

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/12047/62483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have noticed is a known feature or, depending on one's perspective, a bug of the X clipboard system.

A LibreOffice developer, Michael Meeks, [argues this way](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48783#c4):

> The X clipboard system relies on the app owning the selection to
>   provide the data; if you close the app - that app isn't there; so it
>   will fail.
>
> There are various (varyingly expensive) hacks around this out there in
>   various desktops; that try to serialise the clipboard at various
>   points - I guess this could be done before exit.
>
> Problems abound: eg. select 2^36 cells in a sheet, hit copy, exit
>   LibreOffice - what happens ? ;-> but - that's always the way with big
>   sheets I guess.
>
> Are you certain this is an unexpected bug ? :-)

Two blogs in 2010 by an interested student, Sarah Strong, provide readable background information:
  - [GSoC: Clipboard Persistence for Ubuntu](http://sarahestrong.blogspot.com/2010/05/gearing-up-for-gsoc-clipboard.html)
  -  [Clipboard managers for Ubuntu: Patching is hard, let's go shopping! ...for clipboard managers](http://sarahestrong.blogspot.com/2010/06/clipboard-managers-for-ubuntu.html)

She has also written [ClipboardPersistence](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence) which deals with the issue. But note that this wiki page was last updated in 2010 and some links aren't functional; also, the list of applications that "work" and those that don't may be different now with LibreOffice still being a prominent member of the latter. To quote another LibreOffice developer, [Björn Michaelsen](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48783#c5), "since more and more other apps are using the workaround, we start to stick out".

Then, Ask Ubuntu also has information related to your question. Look at [Why might I want to use a clipboard manager?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3335/25656)

So, in answer to your question, just install Parcellite from the Software Center but keep in mind the *potential* performance cost.